# ObservableCollection event handling when part of an object in C#

Tags: c#, events, observablecollection, propertygrid

I have a PropertyGrid object that as a property has an ObservableCollection. I chose this one specifically, because I want to be able to catch events such as adding, removing, ... of the elements of the list. Notice that I don't care if the elements themselves change or not.
Now, I know it's not the greatest of ideas to expose a list as a property, but the user needs to be able to add and remove item as one pleases.
Now, I'm facing a strange problem.
When I subscribe to a CollectionChanged event from somewhere within the code, the event seems to be fired only when the actions Reset and Add are called, and surprisingly (or not:)), not when Remove is called. Here is the detailed code as an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SomeClassThatHasObservable SomeObject = new SomeClassThatHasObservable();
        System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid prpG_ = new System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid();

        int item = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtListCount.Text = "0";
            prpG_.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 15);
            prpG_.Name = "prpG";
            prpG_.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(338, 400);
            prpG_.TabIndex = 1;
            SomeObject.ListOfInts.CollectionChanged += HandleCollectionAddRemove;
prpG_.SelectedObject = SomeObject;
            this.Controls.Add(prpG_);
        }

        private void HandleCollectionAddRemove(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                item++;
            }
            else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                if (item > 0)
                {
                    item--;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class SomeClassThatHasObservable
    {
        public SomeClassThatHasObservable()
        {
            m_ListOfInts = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<int> m_ListOfInts;
        public ObservableCollection<int> ListOfInts
        {
            get { return this.m_ListOfInts; }
        }

    }

}
```

What I've noticed is that when something should be added to the list, first the Reset action is called, then the add action, and when OK is pressed in the end (inside the collection editor), the whole procedure is redone, and exactly as many times as there are items in the list. This is pretty much the same way the "remove" action works, but without actually invoking the Remove action iteslf.

Comment: I don't see you adding or removing items from your ObservableCollection<int>? The issue is likely in code you haven't shown us, the CollectionChanged event will fire on an add or remove and neither should set the reset action like you're currently seeing.

Comment: Hey FrumRoll, the adding and removing part is handled by the CollectionEditor.